# Write a variable to a file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file

This may be a copy.. but I'm not getting the thing I want from the answers I saw..

I just want to save a particular variable into a local file using Javascript. I know how to read a file.

I wrote this code..

```
<script>
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('http://localhost/online/hello.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  else
  {
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
  }
});

</script>
```

What is the error here.. or is there a simple and straight-forward way of doing it..??

Comment: You need to understand the difference between client-side Javascript and Node.js.   You can't do that.

Comment: Whats the deal with those `script` tags? Aren't you using node.js?

Comment: @mzedeler: I doubt it.

Comment: Waaaiiiiiiit a minute. I could've sworn I was able to read and write files locally using JS a few years ago...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to call node-js code from the browser. Although javascript can run in both the browser and on the server (node-js), those are separate systems.

Another thing you can do is google "HTML save file example" and see how this is typically implemented - by opening a save dialog for the user, getting his/her permission, etc. (otherwise any website could just write any file to your computer...).

Answer (score 0):

You are writing `NodeJS` code for client side application. You must understand the difference between `javascript` on browser and `javascript` on NodeJS platform.

`Javascript` is a language just like `C`, `Java` and `Python`

`V8` is a javascript engine to run the `javascript` application. It is something similar to `JRE` for Java.

`Browser`(Only Chrome) uses `V8` engine for running javascript application. Other browsers use different javascript engine. Five years ago, there was only one possibility that javascript can only work on `browser`. You cannot use `javascript` for application programming like `C` and `Java`

`NodeJS` is a platform which uses `V8` to enables developer to write javascript application just like `C`, `Java` program. NodeJS also has some inbuilt library for accessing file system, 
networks, and much more utilities. One of the internal library in NodeJS is `fs`. It only works on `NodeJS` application, not on browser application.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty simply using jrpc-oo. jrpc-oo links the browser and nodejs using the JRPC2 protocol. jrpc-oo abstracts classes over JRPC so that either side (nodejs or the browser) can call eachother.

I have setup an [example repo to do exactly this here](https://github.com/flatmax/lit-jrpc-node/tree/writeFile). Use the writeToFile baranch. I will break out the important parts here.

First in nodejs, we write a class with a method to write input arguments to file. The method looks like so (from the file TestClass.js) :

```
const fs = require('fs');

class TestClass {
  writeToFile(arg){
    fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/browser.json',JSON.stringify(arg));
  }
}
```

In the browser we inherit from the jrpc-oo class JRPCClient and call the server class TestClass and method writeToFile like so (from the file src/LitJRPC.js) :

```
import {JRPCClient} from '@flatmax/jrpc-oo/jrpc-client.js';

export class LitJRPC extends JRPCClient {
  writeObjToFile(){
    // create the argument we want to save to file
    let dat={name:'var',value:10};
    // Ask the server to execute TestClass.writeToFile with args dat
    this.server['TestClass.writeToFile'](dat);
  }
}
```

Finally we run the nodejs app and the web-dev-server and we look at the browser console and nodejs console to see what happened. You will see the browser variable dat saved to the file /tmp/browser.json

As we are using a secure websocket for jrpc, you will need to generate the certificate and clear the certificate with the browser before the app will work. If you don't want to worry about security then don't use secure websockets. Read the readme in the [reference repo](https://github.com/flatmax/lit-jrpc-node/tree/writeFile) for more information on setup and usage.